# How to create a Logic App Custom Connector polling trigger?

Tags: triggers, polling, azure-logic-apps, connector

I've been able to create a Logic App Custom Connector with a webhook trigger by following [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-webhook-trigger), however I can't find any documentation on creating a polling trigger. I was only able to find [Jeff Hollan's trigger examples](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTriggersExample), but the polling trigger doesn't seem compatible with the custom connector.

I tried setting up a polling trigger by performing the following steps:

- Create an Azure Function with a GET operation expecting a date time query parameter
- Have the function return a set of entities that have changed since the last poll
- Configure the custom connector to call the Azure Function with the date time query parameter
- Configure the response body of the custom connector
- Try different things in the 'Trigger configuration' section, but this is most confusing to me.

Whatever I tried, the trigger always fails with a 404 in the trigger outputs, similar to what [I initially had](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93bb2b20-e56b-4e36-83d1-31845c88a3b1/azure-logic-apps-custom-connector-webhook-trigger?forum=azurelogicapps&prof=required) with the webhook trigger type.

There are a few things that confuse me:

**1. Path of trigger query seems screwed up**

It looks like the custom connector UI screws up the path to the trigger. I noticed this when I downloaded the OpenAPI file. The path to my trigger API should be `/api/trigger/tasks/completed`, but in the OpenAPI file it read `/trigger/api/trigger/tasks/completed`. It appears the custom connector adds `/trigger` in front of the path. I sometimes noticed it doing this multiple times, giving me something similar to `/trigger/trigger/trigger/api/trigger/tasks/completed`. I fixed this in the OpenAPI file and re-imported it into the custom connector.

**2. Trigger Configuration section**

I don't understand what to do in the Trigger Configuration section of a polling trigger.

[image]

- I assume the query parameter to monitor state change is some parameter I define myself, e.g. a timestamp, to determine what entities to return.
- As the 'select value to pass to selected query param' I would expect I could pick a timestamp from the trigger response. It looks like I can only pick values from a collection, not scalar values from the response as I would expect. How does that work?
- Is 'trigger hint' just some information or does it actually control something?

Comment: It seems you have figured it out by passing Callback URL as a body parameter.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/93bb2b20-e56b-4e36-83d1-31845c88a3b1/azure-logic-apps-custom-connector-webhook-trigger?forum=azurelogicapps. Can you share the details around this ?

Comment: The solution you refer to is for the webhook trigger. This question is about a polling trigger. With the webhook trigger I tried to feed the callback url as a query parameters, but that apparently doesn't work. Instead if you use the callback url as a body parameter the webhook trigger works.